# postgis: ST_Distance between two geography. Syntax error

Tags: postgresql, gis, postgis

i am trying to running this on my table

```
select ST_Distance (
    select location from utenti where user_id=464,
    select location from utenti where user_id=474604
);
```

having a location column of this type `location geography(POINT, 4326)`

i am getting a syntax error and i'm not understanding why.

how can i achieve my goal?

for example if i select that column in two queries for each users i get a data like this
"0101000020E61000001435F98F528125402AE5B512BAA34540"

and running:

```
select ST_Distance(%s, %s);
```

it works but the distance doesn't seem to be true. hm

Comment: You have to enclose the subqueries in parenthesis.

Comment: You can test this query: `SELECT ST_Distance(a.geom, b.geom)
FROM utenti a, utenti b
WHERE a.user_id=464 AND b.user_id=474604;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments above you can rewrite the query as:

```
SELECT ST_Distance(a.geom, b.geom) FROM utenti a, utenti b WHERE a.user_id=464 AND b.user_id=474604;
```

**BUT** this will give you the distance in degrees (as that is what your points are stored as). So you will want to change your function to be:

```
SELECT ST_Distance_Sphere(a.geom, b.geom) FROM utenti a, utenti b WHERE a.user_id=464 AND b.user_id=474604;
```

[ST_Distance_sphere](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Distance_Sphere.html) will take some of the curvature of the Earth in to account and will return a distance in metres. If you require absolute accuracy and are not worried about speed you can account for all of the Earth's curvature by using [st_distance_spheroid](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Distance_Spheroid.html).

Answer (score 0):

İf you polygon to point distance
    select st_distance(
        st_geomfromtext('POINT (0 0)'), 
        st_geomfromtext('POLYGON ((1 1, 2 1, 2 2, 1 2, 1 1))')
    )

same base spatial geom column for

```
select st_distance(
    st_geomfromtext(c.geom), 
    st_geomfromtext(b.geom)
) from  city c , build b where b.c_ID=c.ID
```